# Angular - Handle a Generic Dictionary in my component which I get back as a response from an HTTP request using HTTPClient

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have a service (in Angular) that makes a POST Request to the back-end:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


public getNamesPerTypes(): Observable<any> {
     const observable = this.http.post<any>(AppConfig.baseUrl + getNamesPerTypesUrl, {});
     return observable;
}
```

The code in my component is:

```
getNames() {
 this.connectionService.getNamesPerTypes()
  .subscribe(
        response => {
              console.log(response);
        },
        err => console.log(err);
  );
}
```

The object I get from the back-end looks as the following:

> {"$type":"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[Types.ConnectionType,
>   Types],[System.String, mscorlib]],
>   mscorlib","Inner":"ConnectionF","Outer":"ConnectionKLD"}

The ConnectionType is an enum in the back-end, some of its values are: Inner, Outer.

How do I get the values of the generic dictionary in my component:

```
"Inner":"ConnectionF",
"Outer":"ConnectionKLD"
```

What I've done so far is:
I've exported a class:

```
export class NameAndConnectionType {
        public name: string;
        public connectionType: ConnectionType;
}
```

Also exported the enum ConnectionType:

```
export enum ConnectionType{
 Inner= 'Inner',
 Outer= 'Outer'
}
```

Now I should probably include in my Angular service the following:

```
http.post<Dictinary<ConnectionType, string>(AppConfig.baseUrl + getNamesPerTypesUrl, {});
```

Or use the class I've exported: NameAndConnectionType

instead of:

```
http.post<any>
```

But I don't think there is a Dictionary type avaliable in TypeScript.

Again, How do I get the values of the generic dictionary in my component, and use them. For example, using console log I want to see in browser's console the following:

Name for Inner connection is: ConnectionF

Name for Outer connection is: ConnectionKLD

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is few way to resolve this. 
I prefer to use Map<>
It would look like this:

```
http.post<Map<T, U>(AppConfig.baseUrl + getNamesPerTypesUrl, {});
```

Or create your own interface for furture use.

```
interface ConnectionTypeMap{
connection: {[key: string]: string};
}
```

OR

```
interface ConnectionTypeMap{
connection: Map<string, string>;
}
```

then impliment it to your variable

```
variable: ConnectionTypemap;
```

//////

```
http.post<ConnectionTypemap>(AppConfig.baseUrl + getNamesPerTypesUrl, {});
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? AFAIK this is just a cast, so the Map<> is not really constructed correctly. Also, doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no class for dictionary in Angular. I too have faced the same issue.
What I did to overcome this problem is I simulated a dictionary type in angular like this below:

```
let variableNames: {[key: string]: string};
```

As I see you need a dictionary of type , you can use the above code, it will solve your problem.

Now to iterate through this variableNames dictionary you should use the below code

```
Object.Keys(variableNames).foreach(key => { your code here. });
```

Hope this helps you achieve your requirement.